# Rails documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just started learning **RubyOnRail** since some days. I need some rubyrails/ rails documentaton/api like [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) with complete and detail explanation that make easy for me to learn. Please Help me about this.

Again apologize if I make some mistake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a detailed API Documentation go to http://api.rubyonrails.org/

If you need some help to get started, look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you've got everything you need to get you started [here](http://rubyonrails.org/documentation)..

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://ruby.railstutorial.org, it's a nice step-by-step tutorial for beginners

Answer (score 1):

If you need some tutorials:

1. First of all: [Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)
2. Then read: **Beginning Ruby: From Novice to Professional**
3. Then some details you can find in book: **The Rails 3 Way, 2nd Edition**
4. Also you find more interesting on this site: [Rails casts](http://railscasts.com)